# Excel is unable to save a shared workbook when there is a dropdown menu somewhere in it, crashes on re-opening or when several users are collaborating

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, office365

I am using Excel 365 to share a file with my team, it is stored on SharePoint. It is an `.xlsm` file, since it contains several macros. The user has to open the file locally in the Microsoft Excel app for the macros to work, which is not an issue, and they work fine. I have a VBA macro that creates dropdown menus in some cells (known as Excel Data Validation), for suggesting values (mainly strings) to the user.

However, the file systematically freezes and Excel eventually crashes, when a dropdown menu is present somewhere in the Workbook (details below). I have narrowed down the problem, to the point where I am almost entirely certain that it only depends on the presence or absence of dropdown menus in my file.

For reference, the VBA code I use to create a dropdown menu is always the same, it works perfectly fine, and is as such (only the range and the array differ):

```
With Range(<some_coordinates>).Validation
  .Delete
  .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=Join(<an_array>, ",")
  .IgnoreBlank = True
  .InCellDropdown = True
  .ShowInput = True
  .ShowError = False
End With
```

This code is triggered by an event handler (`Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`) in a Sheet module, which also triggers other things like cell color formatting, or auto-filling some cells, and doesn't seem to cause any issue.
I make sure to avoid an infinite loop by using these lines at the beginning of the event:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

And these at the end of the script:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

In between, I use some lines to fill cells like so:

```
Cells(row, col).Value = an_array(0)
Cells(row, col).Value = an_array(1)
```

And I also change formatting like so:

```
cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 155)
```

Overall, all of this work fine, the app doesn't freeze, VBA doesn't crash or get in an infinite loop, and collaborating is possible, except when there is a dropdown in the file.
Please find details about my problem below.

#### When collaborating on the file

When 2 or more people are working on the file, opened locally in the Excel app, everything seems to work fine. However, when one of the users creates a dropdown menu (through the macro), all the other users get the following error message:

> Your file wasn't uploaded because your changes cannot be merged with changes made by someone else.

Following this message, excel freezes for all the other users, and eventually crashes. The remaining user is able to save and close the file, and whenever someone re-opens the file, the same issue happens as described in **When alone on the file**.

#### When alone on the file

When working alone on the file, macros work fine, including dropdown menus. I am even able to save the file, and Excel says nothing.
However, when I reopen the file, I get the following error:

> We found a problem with some content in '<file_name>'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

When I click "Yes", I get the following message:

> Excel was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content.

This creates a "Repaired" version of the file, without the dropdown menus, and that can be saved and re-opened later.

---

I tried to remove the dropdown menus, and it resolves the problem (which is why I believe they cause the issue). I tried to use the online version of the file, but there is no point in my case since the macros don't work in Excel online.

So, is there a way to use and save dropdown menus in shared Excel files?

Comment: Do you have any event handling code anywhere in the Workbook (either in Sheet modules or in the ThisWorkbook module)? Also, do you and your other users have any Excel Addins (either VBA or COM) enabled ... if so, try disabling them ... does the crashing continue?

Comment: @JohnM thanks, I clarified the event handler part. Regarding the Excel Addins, I believe I don't use any Addins, or at least I don't remember installing any of those (how can I check, to be sure?)

Comment: It could be your `Worksheet_Change` event handler is itself triggering events (eg if it changes cell values)? Suggest posting the code (as text) as an update/edit to your question. To check for AddIns: File > Options > Add-ins > Manage then look for both 'Excel Add-ins' and 'COM Add-ins' ... anything checked is a loaded Add-in. You need to check on each device concurrently opening the Workbook though as any user could have an Add-in ... hence suggest looking into `Worksheet_Change` first.

Comment: @JohnM Thanks again, I added snippets of code in my question. But I believe the problem comes from somewhere else, as the code works fine for everything (including dropdown menus), until someone tries to save the file. I checked for the Add-ins, and there are none activated for me, but as you said, I would have to check with each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the fix to this problem, so might as well share it here if anyone needs it.

As I said, the dropdown menus make the app crash when several people are on the file, but it's not the case with other macros.
After (a lot of) debugging, we found that the problem comes from the size of the drop-down menu, in number of elements. It seems that the server cannot "push" the modification to other users if the drop-down is too big.

So the easy fix is to limit the number of elements to appear in the drop-down, although it can be inconvenient (it is not too much in my case).
Then, when using the macro, everything works fine and the change is made for others as well. When saving and re-opening the file, everything works fine.